# How do you close Tool Windows in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got a zillion different tool windows all docked & hidden in IntelliJ but what I'd really like to do is to close some of them.  I'll never use them and they're just adding to the visual clutter.  There are buttons for everything BUT closing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [help files](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/appearance.html) it's <kbd>File > Settings > Appearance</kbd> that will help you. You can hide the tool windows by unselecting `Show tool window bars`.

On a case by case basis, you could use <kbd>File > Other Settings > Configure Plugins</kbd>

and work through the wizard unselecting those plugins that you're not using. You'll need to restart *Intellij*, but it'll get rid of 'em.

Comment: I just want to remove SOME of the items on the items on the bars.  Not the actual bars themselves.  I like the idea.. I just really don't need to see Ant Build or Commander or so no and so forth..

Comment: @ShaneC If you're happy to lose functionality then remove the plugins as described in the edited answer.

Comment: You can drag some of them to the lower right toolbar. They're still visible, but at least you have all the ones you don't care about at the same place. But a better solution is probably to remove the plugins, as already proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  The fact I can't just close them is still pretty dumb to me.. oh well :)

Comment: @Gary. And how to we know which windows belongs to which plug-in?

Answer (score 58):

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1489

Problem solved. Please vote-up, my review looks a little lonely all by itself :)

**Edit**

I have started [a discussion on the IntelliJ forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/452160) - please contribute.

Comment: Yeah this should be a default tool. Absolutely perfect- totally what I was looking for.

Comment: I installed this plugin but can't find it in the interface--where is it? Its page says it's located under "Window -> Tool Window Management -> Configure Preferred Availabilities", but there's no "Tool Window Management" option under Window.  ToolWindow Manager also disappeared from the Plugins list after restarting intellij, so I'm not even sure where it went...

Comment: @Amalgovinus Are you sure you actually installed it? The plugin works fine for me and the menu option is there.

Answer (score 8):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (while a tool window is open) may completely close (remove) some types of tool windows.

Comment: On Mac you press ⌘ + Shift + F4

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ 15 (Mac anyway), go to preferences, keymap, search for "Hide All Tool Windows". See what they decided to use for the keyboard shortcut. Then change it to whatever you like. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Tip: When recording a new shortcut, use the mouse to hit Ok, or you may end up with Enter as your shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

The option "Remove from Sidebar" is added to the context menu on tool-window buttons in IntelliJ 15.
ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145126

I found the feature request in the discussion that [Lawrence Wagerfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989433/715077) links to.

Thank you Lawrence!

Answer (score 1):

Found a quirky way to do this (for bottom-of-page tools only) without Intellij 15. Just open the tool window and middle-click its title. It'll go away until summoned again.